# is it possible to get events from transactions that are in the `txpool`?

Tags: transactions, events, pending-transactions, txpool, decentralized-exchange

Is it possible to see the events that will be emitted in the `txpool`, or is only the transaction information available?

For example, can I search in either the `queued` or `pending` transactions and search each transaction for their respective event? If I find someone that is interacting with a DEX, can I see what the result of their transaction will be (the event), or can I just see the input params and associated transaction information?

Answer (score 2):

No, It is Immpossible.
An event is a kind of result of a transaction, like a calculated variable value. So, you can only guess what will happen based on the input data.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible in theory, once transaction is included into pending block, you may try to query its logs via `web3.eth.getPastLogs ({from: 'pending', to: 'pending'})`, though I'm not sure this works in any of existing implementation, and you may need to start mining on your node in order to make this work.  Also, there is no simple way to force particular transactions to be included into pending block.